# Blank Adsense ads with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I have adsense account, but when I put the code in my website it shows only blank space, (

- My Account is verified.. any help?

you can check the website here (Arabic website - ad is above the footer and in sidebar):
http://resheh.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the blank ads on your website. You need to wait a while for the ads to get impressions. It will take some time for them to appear. If it doesn't show up within the next couple days, go [here for help](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/adsense).